# App-Only Token Fetches Users But Can't Create Subscriptions?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I am using an "app-only" token to retrieve my users which works just fine.

Once the app loops through the users, it's supposed to create a subscription as shown below.

However, when attempting to create the subscription, the request simply returns:

> Code: InvalidRequest Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> Inner error

**My question is, why does the subscription request fail to connect** when I am obviously able to successfully connect in the first request which retrieves the users?

How can I see the inner error?

```
string tenantId = appSettings.TenantId;

var client = sdkHelper.GetAuthenticatedClientAppOnly(tenantId);

// this request works...
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await client.Users.Request().Filter("userPrincipalName eq 'MY_USER_PRINCIPAL_NAME'").GetAsync();

if (users?.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (User user in users)
    {
        // this request doesn't work...
        Subscription newSubscription = new Subscription();
        string clientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        newSubscription = await client.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(new Subscription
        {
            Resource = $"users/{ user.Id }@{ tenantId }/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
            //Resource = $"users/{ user.UserPrincipalName }/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages", // also tried using email address
            ChangeType = "created",
            NotificationUrl = "https://localhost:44334/notification/listen",
            ClientState = clientState,
            //ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4230, 0) // current maximum lifespan for messages
            ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0)     // shorter duration useful for testing
        });
    }
}
```

When I wrap the call in a try/catch, the error message is just this with no inner exception:

> Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' was thrown.

I have tried all three resources URLs but all result in the same error as shown above:

- Resource = `$"users/{ user.Id }/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",`
- Resource = `$"users/{ user.Id }@{ tenantId }/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",`
- Resource = `$"users/{ user.UserPrincipalName }/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",`

I found this thread on github but the requests don't seem to work for me.

1. Allow Application-Only requests to create subscriptions - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NotificationUrl cannot be "**localhost**!"  The request is being sent from a remote server so it has no idea what localhost would be thus it fails.  If I deploy my project to a remote server and pass the URL, it will likely work.  I will try that...